# Webfonts and OpenType Old Style Numerals (onum) feature

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, opentype

I'm trying to get ["old style"/hanging numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) to work with `@font-face`-embedded webfonts, and I'm running into... iconsistencies.

Selected findings so far (OSX/Win7):

- In general, low-level syntax (`font-feature-settings: "onum" 1`; optionally prefixed) is fairly well supported in modern browsers; high-level syntax isn't yet (`font-variant-numeric: oldstyle-nums`)
- Firefox is good at it, IE10 is fine, while no support *at all* in Safari (up to 9).
- Google Fonts (at least [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)) do not include the necessary OpenType feature information
- With Chrome it gets "interesting": no display of `onum` unless the word is followed by a `&nbsp;`! Affects Android (4.4 here, cough) and OSX, not Win7?! Maybe there's a logic other than "it's a bug" here that I'm missing; insight, ideas or clarification appreciated.

Here's my ugly [test case](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzXGQN). Nota bene though:

- Google Fonts might get passed thru to your local installed font so deactivate/uninstall
- in the "Open Sans @font-face" columns the capital "W" correctly defaults, because I excluded capital letters from the subset.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It hides in this sentence: "Maybe there's a logic other than "it's a bug" here that I'm missing; insight, ideas or clarification appreciated."

Comment: that still leaves "what is your question", though. "How do I make this work properly across all modern browsers", or "are these bugs"? because if it's the latter, that is not a question for Stackoverflow, that's something that browser issue trackers can tell you (IE, Chromium, Firefox, and WebKit all have open public trackers)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying with Kenneth Ormandy's [Utility OpenType](http://utility-opentype.kennethormandy.com/) which works around all the known browser quirks. If you still run into issues you could [file an issue with the project](https://github.com/kennethormandy/utility-opentype/issues) and if something non-spec is happening, file a bug with the browser makers.